How Deep is Implicit Sharing?
When raising a Case and:

Case.Account = Account Coke
Case.Contact = Related to/Member of Account Pepsi

Then, Case.Contact will have read access to Account Coke, right?
I will now introduce a custom object Customer_Master__c where it has a field-
"Parent_Account__c : Lookup(Account)".
Then, I will add a new field in Case-
Business_Account__c : Lookup(Customer_Master__c)
So now,

Case.Account = Account Coke
Case.Contact = Related to/Member of Account Pepsi
Case.Business_Account__c = Customer Master Dr. Pepper
Case.Business_Account__r.Parent_Account__c = Account Dr. Pepper

Will Case.Contact also have read access to Account Dr. Pepper?

You'll want to read about Implicit Sharing, but basically, the answer is "No." Implicit sharing of the parent only applies to the AccountId field for a case, contact, or opportunity, and only applies in a limited set of circumstances. Your custom relationship will not affect sharing or grant access to records users wouldn't otherwise have.

Thanks, @sfdcfox. I just want to make sure that I'm not missing anything especially when it comes to custom objects.
